# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from SAS

Tags: sas

How can I call an Oracle stored proc from SAS to pass values and return values.  I have SAS/ACCESS and running SAS 9.3

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Check out the SQL passthrough facility maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
proc sql;

connect to oracle (user="oracleUserName" password="pass" path="serverPath" CONNECTION=GLOBAL CONNECTION_GROUP = SASAML);

execute( execute MyPackage.MyProcedure(&param1, &param2) ) by oracle;

/* param1 and param2 are macro variables here */

disconnect from oracle;

quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine in SAS 9.2 and above using ODBC passthrough.

Here's a similar discussion with relevant links:

http://communities.sas.com/message/114296#114296

I'll try and come back sometime to surmise the linked article in this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Pass-through stored procedure execution does not support output parameters. But if you need only one output parameter, a workaround is to use a function and "SELECT FROM dual" query. Here is in example (it uses one input parameter that is passed in from a macro variable).

```
%let a =  'ddd'; 
proc sql;
    connect to oracle as ora2 (user=xxx password=xxx path="xxx");
    select * from connection to ora2 (
    SELECT test_fun(p_a => &a.) FROM dual
    );
    disconnect from ora2;
run;
```